# Do we know how often children were killed aboard the Enterprise-D?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

The *Enterprise*-D is very often to be found in dangerous situations, with casualties reported on, say, Deck 10 and fatalities resulting from attacks by enemy ships.

Is there any reference, in any episodes or EU material, as to how often, if ever, the civilian children on board the *Enterprise*-D were numbered among the civilian casualties?

Comment: Thankfully the weekly poker game successfully distracted Data from his "how tightly should humans hug their offspring?" experiments.

Comment: Are there any children which are not civilian?

Comment: @Mirko Wesley Crusher?

Comment: @Randal'Thor: You have a point there. I didn't think of Wesley.

Answer (score 5):

Troi's son Ian died, at least his human form.

Data's daughter Lal died. I think she could be reasonably called a child, even if her form was adult.

Nurse Ogawa lost her unborn baby in *All Good Things*, but then history changed so it never happened.

And various alternate timelines where the Enterprise was destroyed and everyone died.

Comment: For what it's worth, arguably only the last two items are examples of "dangerous situations" the ship was in.

Comment: I see what you mean, but they are still civilian children deaths, so I thought they were worth including.